# Suggestions for a PHP Ecommerce framework for product customization?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm doing some due diligence into a project whereby a user can very heavily customize a wide array of products with almost countless options. The staff/admins need to setup new product classes and attributes, upload options for each attribute configure costs sizes to each attribute option.

Ive used Magento before and have been looking at [Prestashop's data model](http://doc.prestashop.com/download/attachments/1409078/prestashop-datamodel.png). Developing features for Magento, in the past for me has always felt like swimming in tar and I'm starting to veer to towards rolling a custom build.

For the Ecom gurus out there; is there a PHP framework which allows this kind of thing?

Comment: I don't recommend using prestashop. I ran into much difficulties creating relatively complexe price impact attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend Pimcore to you. I am just developing eshop where products have lots of various attributes and I just love the way Pimcore handles it. It is a general cms, not e-commerce but if you make customized solutions, its object approach is just for you. In Pimcore, it is possible to *setup new product classes and attributes* whenever you wish but you always need some programmatic support. The easier way would be to have just one product class and let it have attributes that allows intended customization like object-bricks (set of additional attributes that you can add to a product) or tables (just a simple structure where a user may specify anything and you can interpret it as you wish). It is very flexible system based on Zend.

Comment: Wow, that looks like a beast... nice!! Looks a lot like a big system I rolled out for a fortune500 a few years back.. this is exactly what I'm after!!!

Comment: It says that it integrates with magento. do you have any more info on this?

Comment: Well, connecting with magento is possible by using soap or rest apis but there is no already made solution. I was also thinking about connecting these two but in the end I decided to use just pimcore. Here is a thread with lots of information about the topic: http://www.pimcore.org/board/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=177.

Comment: hmm, doesnt seem like an active community sadly... nice system though

Answer (score 0):

good day, 
we have simple **pimcore - magento bridge**,

it includes 2 extensions:

magento extension https://github.com/oleksandrmakhno/api-bridge-pimcore

pimcore plugin https://github.com/oleksandrmakhno/api-bridge-magento

easy to extend it with custom api logic, enjoy :)